# What is the origin of 'Why'd you do it?' on Frasier?

Tags: frasier

On Frasier, particularly seasons 8-10, there are a number of instances where a character will ask another 'Why'd you do it?' in an exaggerated fashion. Martin asks Niles when he leaves Eddie in a kennel, and asks Frasier when he throws dancing Santa off the balcony. Noel asks Frasier when he doesn't uphold a deal to get Scott Bakula's autograph. There are a couple others, and they all say it the same way! What is the origin and significance of this line and delivery?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're referencing something, but can't remember what... :( [And I think I saw it quoted in other shows]

Comment: Possibly Rocky III; "*Geez, Mick. Why'd ya do it?*" or Warriors "*Why'd you do it? Why'd you waste Cyrus?*"

Comment: It's about the inflection, though, not just the text. Don't remember how they said the line in *Rocky III*, but that's definitely *not* the way they said it in *The Warriors*, where it's uttered in a rather casual tone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is a reference to the song "Why'd You Do It?" by Marianne Faithfull. The inflection on "do" is exactly the same as Faithfull's.

Here's a link to the song on YouTube, but be aware the lyrics are NSFW.

[Why'd You Do It?](https://youtu.be/3mvAMEaWgTQ)